# Exercise on divisibility.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I am a first-year undergraduate student and I kindly request your help for the following exercise:

> Let $b$ be a natural number. The remainder of $4373/b$ is $8$ and the remainder of $826/b$ is $7$. Find $b$.

Step 1: We note that $4373$ and $826$ are coprime and: $$\begin{align}4373 &= ab + 8, \\ 826 &= zb + 7.\end{align}$$ ($a$, $z$ are the quotients of the Euclidean divisions $4373/b$ and $826/b$, in that order).

Step 2: $4373 - 8 = 4365$ and $826 - 7 = 819 \implies 4365/819 = 485/91$. I have deduced that $a = 485$ and $z = 91$.

Step 3: The remaining work is easy. ($b= 4365/485 = 9$)

By chance, the only common divisor of $4365$ and $819$ is $9$ (so $a$ and $z$ are coprime). How to prove that $a$ and $z$ are coprime too? (Let me remind you that $4373$ and $826$ are coprime, that is undoubtedly where to begin from.)

Thanks!

Comment: I think $4363$ in the last paragraph must be a typo since $9$ doesn't divide it. I guess it should be $4365$?

Comment: If you already have that $a$ and $z$ are coprime, then why are you trying to prove that $a$ and $z$ are coprime?

Comment: From $4365 = ab$ and $918 = zb$ you can only derive that $b$ must divide both $4365$ and $918$. But from $4373/b = 8$ you can also "derive" that $b > 8$. So you are looking for a value $b > 8$ dividing both $4365$ and $918$, of which there is only one. So you get $b$, $z$ and $a$, where $z$ and $a$ are coprime. (If $z$ and $a$ are not coprime, can you find another solution $b$?)

Answer (score 1):

From step 1, you know that b divides 4365 and also 819, so it divides gcd(4365,819).

By the Euclidean algorithm, gcd(4365,819)=9 since

$4365=5(819)+270,\;\;\;    819=3(270)+9,\;\;\;  270=30(9)$

(or since $4365=5\cdot9\cdot97$ and $819=7\cdot9\cdot13$).

Therefore b is a divisor of 9, and $b>8$ (as pointed out by TMM) since the
remainder when 4373 is divided by b is 8; so b=9.

Comment: I am no longer preoccupied by the exercise itself as much as I am interested in how to prove that a and z, regardless their values, are coprime, knowing that 4373 = ab + 8 and 826 = zb + 7 are coprime. Proving that allows us to say that b is the unique common factor between 4365 and 819 and that (4365/819 = 485/91) 485 and 91 are respectively the results of 4365/b and 819/b. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can deduce that a and z are coprime from this fact.  For example, $26=2\cdot9+8$ and $43=4\cdot9+7$ are coprime, but 2 and 4 are not coprime.

Comment: Okay, so I was just lucky that a = 485 and z = 91 were coprime. Thank you for your help all.